# What ORM can handle recursion

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, orm

I am using C# ASP.NET and have a requirement to use recursion through out the application. I am currently using Linq to Entities and searched extensively online but could not find and elagant way to perform recursive queries. I will not know how many levels the recursion will go.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to solve, and I ended up writing a helper function which recursed down my data source and returned an IEnumerable with all items in order.  In my case, however, the data source was linear.  If yours is more of a tree structure, and must be displayed hierarchically, this won't really work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exact problem you have and I don't know what other ORMs are doing.

I think NHibernate should solve most of the problems straight forward.

- Use Lazy-loading: children are lazily loaded. You don't need something like recursive queries, which are not possible in SQL.
- Navigation with lazy loading works in both directions. So you can get a node from the database using a simple query and navigate to its parent.
- In many cases it makes sense to add some additional redundancy to the recursive graph. For instance a reference to the root node, which allows queries to trees which have at least one node matching a criterion. Or the depth of a node (its distance to the root). Or the number of child nodes and so on. Whatever you need for your queries.